# Solve I.V.P for differential using quadratic form

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, quadratic-forms

Solve the i.v.p for $y''+4y'+5y=0, y(\frac{\pi}{2})=1/2, y'(\frac{\pi}{2})=-2$

I solved using the quadratic form. and I got $\lambda = \frac{(-4 \pm 2i)}{2}$, which for $\lambda 1,2= 2+2i$.

And then for both my $\alpha$ and my $\beta$, I got 2.

$y(t)=Ae^{(2t)}\cos(2t)+Be^{(2t)}\sin(2t)$ bringing me to $y(t)=e^{(2t)}(A\cos(2t)+B\sin(2t))$

And then I would

(1) $y(t)=e^{(2(\pi/2))}(A\cos(2(\pi/2)+B\sin(2(\pi/2)))=1/2  = -e^{(\pi/2)}*(A+B)=1/2$

(2) $y'(t) =e^{(2(\pi/2))}(-A\sin(2(\pi/2)+B\cos(2(\pi/2)))=-2 = -e^{(\pi/2)}*(A+B)=-2$

I am not quite sure how to find my $A$ and $B$, but would my $A=1/2$ and my $B=-2$

Thus giving me $y(t)=1/2e^{(\pi-2t)} (\sin(t)+2\cos(t))$?

Comment: Solution for $y(t)$ is correct.

Comment: Yay lol! So did I work it out correctly! I'm so glad. On our test, I couldnt figure out my sol.

Comment: You know that you can take $y(t)$, put it back into the DEQ and make sure you get $0$ to validate it. Clear?

Comment: Yes it is very clear! Thank you again.